# MySQL - REGEX Search word from string and matched word should be either alnum or numeric only

Tags: mysql, regex

Question: If i pass any word in where clause then query should return only if passing word is alnum or num only using mysql regex.

I have a table where addresses.

```
address table 
--------------------
 id    | name
--------------------
  1    | 123 demo
--------------------
  2    | 1st demo
--------------------
  3    | 123
--------------------
  4    | demo
```

**Example 1**

```
SELECT * FROM address WHERE name regexp '(^|[[:space:]])123([[:space:]]|$)'
```

**Result**: Row 1,3 should return. it works for me

**Example 2**

```
SELECT * FROM address WHERE name regexp '(^|[[:space:]])1st([[:space:]]|$)'
```

**Result**: Row 2 should return. it works for me

**Example 3**

```
SELECT * FROM address WHERE name regexp '(^|[[:space:]])demo([[:space:]]|$)'
```

**Result**: It should not return any row. but it return 1,2,4 row

**Final** :  **So if i pass "demo" in where clause then no result should return.**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/acc5c8/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to recommend wordboundary syntax like this: `REGEXP '[[:<:]]demo[[:>:]]'`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d63e05/1

Honestly, if this were my project, I'd be doing a `ctype_alnum()` check on the search value before bothering to make a trip to the database.  However, your requirement is:

> only if passing word is alnum or num only using mysql regex

To ensure that the needle string in the query contains at least one number, add another check to the WHERE clause.

More specifically...

```
SELECT * FROM address WHERE address REGEXP '[[:<:]]demo[[:>:]]' AND 'demo' REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

This will return no rows as desired.

Comment: if i pass "demo" in where clause then no result should return

Comment: I dont want in result example : 3, only example 1,2 should works

Comment: Thanks, man it works initially, I will test more with my scenarios. I will try to use ctype_alnum() if possible

Comment: The OP's Question is still imprecise, but you might want the second part to be `REGEXP '^[0-9]'`

Comment: Sure.  That may be true.  (no matter the logical requirement, I wouldn't be using mysql to validate the input string)